# I have added the download apk file functionality in c# dot net but after download the file size is different from actual APK file size

Tags: c#

```
DataSet dsmenuMS = new DataSet();
                dsmenuMS = SQLHelper.ExecuteDataset(Security.ConnectionString(), CommandType.Text, "select Apk from TblAppVersionManagement where id=" + id);

            if (dsmenuMS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string apk = dsmenuMS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Apk"].ToString();



                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/UploadSlip/apkfiles/") + apk);
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
                Response.End();
              }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not clear. You displayed a title that gives us clues on what your problem is, but a deeper explanation (like how the sizes differ, if there is a pattern...) would be **very** helpful to us experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/UploadSlip/apkfiles/") + apk);
```

and confirm the path